# Django Subquery with Scalar Value

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

Is it possible to compare subqueries results with scalar values using Django ORM? I'm having a hard time to convert this:

```
SELECT payment_subscription.*
FROM payment_subscription payment_subscription
  JOIN payment_recurrent payment_recurrent ON payment_subscription.id = payment_recurrent.subscription_id
WHERE
  payment_subscription.status = 1
  AND (SELECT expiration_date
       FROM payment_transaction payment_transaction
       WHERE payment_transaction.company_id = payment_subscription.company_id
             AND payment_transaction.status IN ('OK', 'Complete')
       ORDER BY payment_transaction.expiration_date DESC, payment_transaction.id DESC
       LIMIT 1) <= ?
```

The main points are:

1. The last comparison of the scalar value of the subquery with an arbitrary parameter.
2. the join between the subquery and the outer query with the company id

Answer (score 1):

```
Subscription.objects.annotate(
    max_expiraton_date=Max('transaction__expiration_date')
).filter(
    status=1,
    recurrent__isnull=False,  # [inner] join with recurrent
    transaction__status__in=['OK', 'Complete'],
    max_expiraton_date=date_value
)
```

This produces other SQL query, but obtains the same `Subscription` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can (as of Django 1.11) annotate on a subquery, and slice it to ensure you only get the "first" result. You can then filter on that subquery annotations, by comparing to the value you want.

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Subquery, OuterRef

expiration_date = Transaction.objects.filter(
    company=OuterRef('company'),
    status__in=['OK', 'Complete'],
).order_by('-expiration_date').values('expiration_date')[:1]

Subscription.objects.filter(status=1).annotate(
    expiration_date=Subquery(expiration_date),
).filter(expiration_date__lte=THE_DATE)
```

However...

Currently that can result in really poor performance: your database will evaluate the subquery twice (once in the where clause, from the filter, and again in the select clause, from the annotation). There is work underway to resolve this, but it's not currently complete.